# AS3 (Pixelfumes Reflection Class)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Hi I am using a reflection class in my code. I have stripped it right down to the code below. I have a mc on the stage with an instance name of sand. I have tried all combinations and do not get an error BUT i don't get a reflection either. I have been on the forums for the site but cant find any info. Does anyone have any experience with this plugin please ?

```
import com.pixelfumes.reflect.*;

new Reflect({mc:sand, alpha:100, ratio:255, distance:0, updateTime:0.2, reflectionAlpha:100, reflectionDropoff:3.64});
```

Answer (score 0):

i have NO experience with that particular code but my guess would be that you need to add the reflection to the display list:

```
addChild(new Reflect({mc:sand, alpha:100, ratio:255, distance:0, updateTime:0.2, reflectionAlpha:100, reflectionDropoff:3.64}));
```